# Suggest Box options for relation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have two tables, Application and Client. Application has One Client, Client can have many Applications. I want to use a suggest box to select the client in an application form.

I got it to work with "Suggest Box Query Options" but that only uses startsWith. I want to be able to get suggestions for any word in a string, not just the first one. If I set the "Options" to a string list it does have the desired behavior.

My problem is I don't know how to pick the "Value". I can't pick the foreign key field (Created from adding relation) because it takes a record not a string. And I don't know if I can use a list of relations for the option.